# Proof, that a set is not convex

Tags: banach-spaces

I try to solve the problem 106 of the scottich book. 
I know the set of all rearranged sums is convex.
Let $f_{j,k}$ the indicator function of the interval $(\frac{j}{2^k},\frac{j+1}{2^k}$). k = 0,1,2,$\cdots$  and j = 0..$2^k-1$.
I have proofed, that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_k = f_{0,0} - f_{0,0} + \cdots$ -> 0.
I also  have proofed, that the rearrangement :
$f_{0,0} + f_{0,1} + f_{1,1} - f_{0,0} + \cdots$ converges to the indicator function $1$.

In the scottish it is asked for a solution in infinite-dimensional room.
The book of Werner - "Funktionalanalysis" presents in chapter V6.26 an idea.
Proof: The set {x $ \in L²[0,1]:$ there exist a reorder with x =  $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_\pi(i)$}  is not convex.
The $x_n$ are from type $\mathbb{Z}$

And this proof is my problem. I don't want the solution, just a tip or breadcrumbs :).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For every $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ try to combine $f$'s in such an order that as a sum you will get constant function over interval $(0;1)$ equal $a$. After that try to think of a rearrangement of other terms which converges to $0$.